# Error in JQuery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hello I am trying to get a value from an HTML option tag but i'm getting the next error:

```
function get_states(){
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            **var id = $(this).val;** it says that the error is here but I don't see it
            url: 'competitors/get_states.php',
            method: 'post',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: {id = id}
        }).done(function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }).fail(function(msg, TxtStatus){
            alert("fallo: "+ TxtStatus);
        });     
    });
};
```

Hope you can help me, have a nice day.

Comment: And what is _the next error_??

Comment: `val` is a method and not a property, so use `var id = $(this).val();`

Answer (score 2):

```
var id = $(this).val;
```

Should be

```
var id = $(this).val();
```

**.val** is a property, **.val()** is a method

To get the value of an element from jQuery, you need to use **.val()**

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Honestly didn't see your comment

Comment: I dont care, its my UV